# hibernate adds prefix to table name and thus cannot find it

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have user entity, the following code contains important things for the problem i am facing ( so i am omiting stuff )

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    private List<UserGroupInvite> invites;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<UserGroupInvite> getInvites() { return invites; }
    public void setInvites(List<UserGroupInvite> invites) { this.invites = invites; }
}
```

And UserGroupInvite entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_group_invite")
    public class UserGroupInvite implements Serializable {
        private User user;
        @Id
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id") // in DB the row is called user_id
        @MapsId
        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }
    }
```

However when i retrieve User from database and call:

```
user.getInvites().get(0).getSomePropertyOfInviteIhaveOmitted()
```

the hibernate complains about:

> Table 'databasename.user_user_group_invite' doesn't exist

Why is it looking for **user_user_group_invite** instead of **databasename.user_group_invite** ?

In my hibernate-cfg.xml i have defined

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.project.model.User" />
    <mapping class="com.project.model.UserGroupInvite" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Yet it is looking for wrong name.

**However** when i try to insert into user_group_invite table it works. So why is hibernate behaves in this way?

Thanks for help!

//edit

Now i realized that inserting looks also for table **databasename.user_user_group_invite**, however when i remove **fetch = FetchType.EAGER** it starts to work, why is this happening? I have added fetch = FetchType.EAGER , now i am even more confused

Comment: Check if the annotations `Entity` and `Table` are from jpa package.

Comment: they are all from javax.persistence, if it was wrong annotation inserting wouldnt work either no?

Answer (score -1):

*first*, javax.persistence should be the correct import- dont change that.

*second*, try and remove the @Table annotation above the class definition. if I'm not mistaken, hibernate will generate the DB on it's own, and without the table names hard coded, it might be simpler for the system to find everything where it left it.

if all of the above does not work, try and keep these changes, but now- redirect hibernate to a new DB file. I've encountered some problems while trying to change an existing DB.
if your using spring, define the 'datasource' with a new address pointing at a new file, thus letting hibernate create the DB from scratch, using what I've suggested above.